# Cannot access the pdf file?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have a file in PDF format. But when I open it, I get this error message:

> windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

What could be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur if any of the following scenarios exist on your PC.

You do not have permissions to the file or the file location 
The file is in a location that is not currently accessible as a local network
or an external drive that is not connected to PC The file has been
   moved or deleted The file is corrupt or the shortcut The file may be
   blocked by Windows Antivirus software may be blocking the file